# Loading a style (.qml) via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to load a (.qml) style file to a specific layer, I tried this:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)
if layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBLineString:
    layer.loadNamedStyle('styles/lines.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Also, I tried this:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)
if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
    layer.loadNamedStyle('styles/lines.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

But I get this error:

```
if layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBLineString:

# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'wkbType'
```

Comment: FYI `QGis.WKBLineString` was in QGIS old series 1.x and 2.x. `layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBLineString:` should be now `layer.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineString`. See doc at https://qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html#a70dff7aceefd4b16909f038e32aece11 @ben-w has already answered for your overall issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `mapLayersByName()` returns a list. To return a layer object you need to index the list to access its first element (assuming there is only one layer by that name in your project) e.g.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
if layer.geometryType() == 1:#Line geometry
    layer.loadNamedStyle('path\\to\\style_file.qml')
```

Comment: Correct about the list. I would really keep `if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:`. It makes the code more readable instead of having to keep an index.